React 18 content editable field focus issue
I am working on a quiz application where answers to a question are managed with content editable. I use React 18 for front-end development. I use Dummy options(id= 0) to add options faster and allow the user to change the option text. In Onsuccess original ID is assigned. But If the user adds an option and changes text suddenly, the state changes to onSuccess and the focus of the cursor is out. How can I solve it?
     const restoreCursorPosition = () => {
        if(props.addOptionStatus !== 'click'){
        if (editableRef.current) {
      // Save current selection
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      if (selection) {
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(editableRef.current);
        range.collapse(false); // Set cursor to end of content
        console.log(range)
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
      }
      }
      }
      else{
      editableRef.current.focus()
      }
     };

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2,props.addOptionStatus)
    restoreCursorPosition()
    }, [props.html]); 

I did this to solve the issue. This solves the issue partially. By doing so, instead of focusing out, the cursor goes to the initial position and comes to the original position
